# Does regular XHTML inputText tag have automatic escapement for XML entities like h:inputText in JSF?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, xss, facelets

In another word, in order to prevent XSS in web applications, is it necessary to replace a xhtml inputText with JSF's `h:inputText`? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Note: there's no such thing as a "xhtml inputText". It's is essentially plain template text for JSF.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate more on the it please? So what is the difference between a inputText field and `h:inputText`? What does the `h` specify here?

Comment: :ssssamuel: start with a jsf 101 tutorial and you'll know